# How to find the coordinates of a point lying on a circle, knowing the coordinates of another point and the angle between them

Tags: java, math, geometry

I want to find the blue point 
I know the red point b 
and the angle between 2 radii

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWqzS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the red point has coordinates `(B.x, B.y)`. We know the origin point `(A.x, A.y)`. We know the angle between the points `theta`. We want to find `(C.x, C.y)`. I will be assuming 2d geometry, as this is what your reference shows.

Using a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), we can subtract `B` by `A` to place `A` at the origin, then applying the matrix with the angle given.

Thus, given

`B_new = (B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y)`,

`C = (B_new.x * cos(theta) - B_new.y * sin(theta), B_new.x * sin(theta) + B_new.y * cos(theta)) + (A.x, A.y)`

Comment: Thank you, I see what I wanted in the wiki